# Magento Extension not work properly on backend

Tags: magento, extension-methods

I have an issue with Ves Contentslider of VenusTheme as it dose not load properly on backend. It still works fine on front end but we cannot do any configuration as it's control panel does not load the content. This is pretty weird as we have not changed any thing in our site recently. Please have a look at the screen shot below to have better understanding. Thank you in advance.

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X60Wx.gif)

Comment: Did you clear all caches, logout, and then log back in to admin panel? Normal procedure for new module installation.

Comment: Hi, this extension is an old one I it worked perfect in the past but now it turns out that the control panel not load the configuration content

Comment: Have you installed this extension via Magento Connect or you have uploaded it manually ?

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this issue and thanks to the Venus Theme team for the quick and accurate suggestion. I did compress the js&css files and it stop the website rendering the js&css codes properly. That is why the configaration panel did not load on the admin site. So, I just need to go to the back end and navigate to Configuration/Advanced/Developers/JavaScript Settings(CSS Settings) and chose No option for the Merge JavaScript Files(Merge CSS Files). Then everything work perfectly again. This is good to know when we consider compress our CSS and JavaScript files. Cheers